# c# async methods with BLE

Tags: c#, ios, bluetooth, async-await

I am having trouble with the treading on this bluetooth code. I am using this library https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le. It works as intended for android (samsung SM G900V Api 23) but when I run it on iOS (iphone 6 10.3) the updates are never triggered unless I add a break point. I've tried a couple different things but I am new to c# and threading. What am I doing wrong?

```
public async void ConnectToDeviceService(IDevice device)
{
    service = await device.GetServiceAsync(Guid.Parse(_UUIDS.SERVICE_UUID));

    infoCharacter = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(_UUIDS.DEVICE_INFO_UUID));
    infoCharacter.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
    {
        var bytes = args.Characteristic.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("Characteristic Value: {0}", bytes);
        PrintByteArray(bytes);
    };

    await infoCharacter.StartUpdatesAsync();
}
```

Tried this as well

```
await infoCharacter.StartUpdatesAsync().ContinueWith(result =>
{
    infoCharacter.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
    {
        var bytes = args.Characteristic.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("Characteristic Value: {0}", bytes);
        PrintByteArray(bytes);
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution but I don't fully understand why it seems like there is a race condition on iOS between the event handler being added to the variable and the updates starting? This problem does not occur for me on android devices.

The solution:

```
public async void ConnectToDeviceService(IDevice device)
{
    service = await device.GetServiceAsync(Guid.Parse(_UUIDS.SERVICE_UUID));

    infoCharacter = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(_UUIDS.DEVICE_INFO_UUID));
    infoCharacter.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
    {
        var bytes = args.Characteristic.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("Characteristic Value: {0}", bytes);
        PrintByteArray(bytes);
    };

    await Task.Delay(1000);
    await infoCharacter.StartUpdatesAsync();
}
```